# reference to creating class instance for class defined within creating class

Tags: python, class, jython

I have the following structure:

```
class foo(object):
  class bar(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
      self._parent=parent             #this

    def worker(self):
      return self._parent.name

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name=name

  def giveNamePointer(self):
    return self.bar(self)             #and this
```

Which works fine, however I was wondering if there is an implicit or easier way to get the reference to the creating instance in the special case, that the created instance is a class defined in the creating class.

**edit**: could this help me :[implementing descriptiors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [Explicit is better than implicit.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

(There's nothing special about defining a class inside another class.)

Comment: well the surrounding scope changes, but i will accept pythons zen

Comment: what about [Implementing Descriptors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)